# Unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

When I run this program I get error:

> (repl):17: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

```
i = 0
numbers = []
while i < 100
    if i%3 == 0 and i%5 == 0
        numbers.push('FizzBuzz')
    else if i%3 == 0
        numbers.push('Fizz')
    else if i%5 == 0
        numbers.push('Buzz')
    else
        numbers.push(i)
    end
    i += 1
end
numbers.each do |number|
    puts number
end
```

Comment: Hint: `else if`, check out your Ruby syntax docs.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby there's `elsif` instead of `else if`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your ruby `if` syntax use `elsif` syntax instead of `else if`.

To check syntax please see link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm